# Accessing data from express route into view

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a username JSON object which is being stored in as "bootstrappedUser". It is only defined on successful login. How would I make this available to the view (embed this object into the html source code) in ejs if it is defined?

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs',{
      bootstrappedUser: req.user
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access this in EJS via:

```
<div>
    <%= bootstrappedUser %>
</div>
```

Comment: Great that works! I made it more complicated than it had to be.